# adding variable to savedInstanceState from onCreateView method of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, inner-classes, screen-rotation

I am attempting to retain data via the savedInstanceState bundle (and eventually to restore it) for when my screen rotates. But the data is coming from an editText field in an afterTextChanged event.  Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View V= inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputscreen, container, false);
final EditText loan_amount =(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.inp_loan_amount); 
final EditText the_Rate =  (EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.inp_interest_rate); 

if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
loan_amount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("loanAmount"));
            }

loan_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
     {
    @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
 @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {} 
 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("loanAmount","Test Message");  
}
}
```

});

In the above code I am using "Test Message" in lieu of the actual string from the EditText field just for simplicity sake.  The error is the "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method" error because I am referring to the savedInstanceState bundle within the inner class.  But the EditText field doesn't exist before the inflate function within OnCreateView, so I need to save the data here.  Adding "final" to the savedInstanceState bundle gives me in a NullException error.

So basically I need to know how to successfully save data generated by an inner class (addTextChangedListener) to the savedInstanceState Bundle in order to restore it after a screen rotation.  If there is a simple way to do it, I'm an idiot!  Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't doing anything complex you can also use an xml attribute on the EditText to save your text:

```
android:freezesText="true"
```

Comment: Unfortunately the EditText fields need to be constantly accepting new input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right approach from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).

Comment: Is this the right approach when dealing with screen rotations?  I thought that was the purpose of the onSavedInstanceState event.  The link you provided makes no specific mention of screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save it in saveInstanceState method and resotre it after orientation change.Similar to below code.

```
EditText loan_amount;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputscreen, container, false);

    loan_amount =(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.inp_loan_amount);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        loan_amount.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("loanAmount"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("loanAmount", loan_amount.getText().toString());
}
```

If any query feel free to ask.